# substring extraction from a string in H2 database

Tags: h2

I need to extract a part of string from a main string.
i have tried

```
CALL SUBSTR('<A href="MY String" title="Click for test">669253-121</A>', -14,10)
```

but the value 669253-121 may not always be of size 10.

Is it possible to write an nested query to do so?

Comment: You need to use LOCATE function. Essentially, it's h2 version of indexOf.

http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=substring&search=substring#locate